# Insert user in PeopleOrGroup Field using javascript SharePoint 2013

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I have only email address of user.
How to insert user in PeopleOrGroup Field using javascript SharePoint 2013.
If I directly pass email address to filed like

```
var MyUserEmail = 'mymanger's email adress' \\email id is proper and checked
oListItem.set_item('MyFieldName',MyUserEmail);
```

Throwing error as invalid data.

Comment: **var avt = new SP.FieldUserValue();
avt.set_lookupId(18);
oListItem.set_item('MyFieldName',avt);**

This works. Now how to get Id from Email address.? or any other way to save data in PeopleOrGroup Field?

Comment: Please don't post code in comments. Edit your question and include further details there.

Answer (score 1):

The following code for your reference:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = ctx.get_web();
    var lists = web.get_lists();
    var list = lists.getByTitle("CL");
    var item = list.getItemById(1);

    var assignedToVal = new SP.FieldUserValue();
    var MyUserEmail = "app@xx.com";
    var userId=GetUserId(MyUserEmail);
    assignedToVal.set_lookupId(userId);   //specify User Id 
    item.set_item("MyFieldName",assignedToVal);
    item.update();
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(
        function() {
            console.log('Updated');
        },
        function(sender,args) {
            console.log('An error occurred:' + args.get_message());
        }
    );
});
function GetUserId(emailAddress){
    var userId="";

    var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/siteusers?$select=Id&$filter=Email eq '"+emailAddress+"'";

    //execute AJAX request
    $.ajax({
        url: requestUri,
        type: "GET",
        headers: { "ACCEPT": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            if(data.d.results.length>0){
                userId=data.d.results[0].Id;
            }

        },
        error: function () {
            //alert("Failed to get details");                
        }
    });
    return userId;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: Code which works]

My code which is working. Do the Rest call. you can keep Ajax call as Asynchronous false to get the item before Execution Asynchronous () for item save